# when i run npm run i get error ---Property 'ngControl' in type 'MtxColorPickerComponent' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatFormF

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-package, npm-run

when i run npm run i get error ---Property 'ngControl' in type 'MtxColorPickerComponent' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatFormF....I am using visual studio code. terminal to run it

eror TS2416: Property 'ngControl' in type 'MtxColorPickerComponent' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatFormF

ERROR in node_modules/@ng-matero/extensions/color-picker/color-picker.component.d.ts:15:5 - erorms/forms").NgControl' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/projects/UI/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms").NgControl'.
ror TS2416: Property 'ngControl' in type 'MtxColorPickerComponent' is not assignable to the sa
me property in base type 'MatFormFieldControl'.

ngControl: NgControl;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ng-matero/extensions/select/select.component.d.ts:17:5 - error TS2416: Property 'ngControl' in type 'MtxSelectComponent' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatFormFieldControl'.

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:42, open your browser on http://localhost:42/ **

I tried "npm install @ng-matero/extensions --force" to fix it. but i still get error. Any ideas?